# jMeter System Properties from Pom File

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have to pom file as below to set a 4 JMeter system properties

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jmeter-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipNFTs}</skipTests>
        <generateReports>true</generateReports>
        <reportDirectory>${basedir}/target/reports/${performanceTest}</reportDirectory>
        <logsDirectory>${basedir}/target/reports/${performanceTest}</logsDirectory>
        <jmeterExtensions>
            <artifact>org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.16.0</artifact>
        </jmeterExtensions>
        <junitLibraries/>
        <propertiesSystem>
            <javax.net.ssl.trustStore>${project.build.directory}/target/jmeter/keystore/eskort_keystore.keystore</javax.net.ssl.trustStore>
            <javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword>P@ssw0rd</javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword>
            <javax.net.ssl.keyStore>${basedir}/target/jmeter/keystore/eskort_keystore.keystore</javax.net.ssl.keyStore>
            <javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>P@ssw0rd</javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword>
        </propertiesSystem>
</plugin>
```

the output that i take is :

```
 #Thu Jun 08 17:42:06 EEST 2023 javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C\:\\MyTools\\GitRepo\\Compliance\\performance/target/jmeter/keystore/eskort_keystore.keystore
 javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=P@ssw0rd
 avax.net.ssl.trustStore=C\:\\MyTools\\GitRepo\\Compliance\\performance\\targt/target/jmeter/keystore/eskort_keystore.keystore
 javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=P@ssw0rd
 sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
```

the problem is is not usable due to the **C\ :** at the beginning of the path .

how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `eskort_keystore.keystore` lives at the same folder where pom.xml - you should use `${project.basedir}/eskort_keystore.keystore` instead.

I don't know where did you get this "output" but Maven and Java should handle Windows file paths without any issues.

[image]

As you can see the [Groovy script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) in the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) checks the path and the presence of the keystore file under the given path and succeeds.

More information: [Maven Properties Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are mixing variables:

${project.build.directory} is results in the path to your "target" directory.

${basedir} represents the directory containing pom.xml

so in the system property <javax.net.ssl.trustStore> you are adding an extra "target" that is not needed.
you should check/review what do you have in your target folder and after set the properties accordingly.

Note:
normally a the keystore file usually has a .jks extension.